# operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool' linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use ternary operator in a linq query like below

```
ordersupplierinvoiceSort = ordersupplierinvoiceSort
                .Where(a => a.OrderSupplierInvoiceVATs.Any(b => b.VATPercentage = from.Value.Year < 2017 ? 8 : 10 && b.DeletedOn == null && b.DeletedByUserId == null && b.OrderSupplierInvoice.TransactionTypeId == 1));
```

But i am getting this error
`operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'`

Help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `(from.Value.Year < 2017 ? 8 : 10)`

Comment: This not returning bool: `b => b.VATPercentage = from.Value.Year < 2017 ? 8 : 10`. Probably you want to do this: `b => b.VATPercentage == (from.Value.Year < 2017 ? 8 : 10)` (note `==` instead of `=`).

Comment: @Sinatr did that. but then again an error `Constant value 2017 cannot be converted to a bool`

Comment: @Isuru, see edit, I posted quickly and went in search for duplicate, unfortunately couldn't find one, it's all about [operator precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: You cant do && between bool and int. My guess is  b.VATPercentage == (from.Value.Year < 2017 ? 8 : 10) you want this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need `==` instead of `=` if you want to compare two values.

I guess `from` is a local variable, then you can calculate the percentage also before the query:

```
int percentage = from.Value.Year < 2017 ? 8 : 10;
ordersupplierinvoiceSort = ordersupplierinvoiceSort
    .Where(a => a.OrderSupplierInvoiceVATs
         .Any(b => b.VATPercentage == percentage 
                && b.DeletedOn == null 
                && b.DeletedByUserId == null 
                && b.OrderSupplierInvoice.TransactionTypeId == 1));
```

This improves readability and works. Otherwise you need to wrap it within parentheses because of the rules of [operator precedences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is [*operator precedence*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx). The `&&` operator has higher priority than the ternary operator, so use parenthesis:

```
ordersupplierinvoiceSort = ordersupplierinvoiceSort
         .Where(a => a.OrderSupplierInvoiceVATs
         .Any(b => b.VATPercentage == (from.Value.Year < 2017 ? 8 : 10) && 
                   b.DeletedOn == null && 
                   b.DeletedByUserId == null && 
                   b.OrderSupplierInvoice.TransactionTypeId == 1));
```

Plus you miss a `=` at `b.VATPercentage == (from...`.